# Test train data split - Machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, training-data, train-test-split

I am trying to do some test train split (90% and 10%) and used below query

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pdf.drop(columns = list(set(cols_not_used).union(set(['RANK'])))) , pdf['RANK'], random_state = 13, train_size = 0.9)

But in my dataframe I have "date" column and would like to split train and test based on date.
i.e., test data as latest 3 months information and the rest as train dataset.

Please let me know how that can be done.

Comment: If you are going to separate train/test based on date you are better of slicing based on the date. E.g., `df[‘date’]>3_month_prior`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to proceed, but you can sort the data by time.

```
df = df.sort_values(by="date")
```

After sorting it by time you can create your train test set:

```
import numpy as np 
train_set, test_set = np.split(data, [int(0.9 *len(df))])
```

The next step is to simply split between your predictory and explanatory variables:

```
xtrain = train_set.drop('Survived', axis=1)
ytrain = train_set['Survived']
xtest = test_set.drop('Survived', axis=1)
ytest = test_set['Survived']
```